# Jena model.setNsPrefixes through java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, jena

Here is the code：

```
  *Location location = Location.create("target/DBLP");
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(location);
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
    Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
    HashMap<String, String> prifixMap = new HashMap<>();
    prifixMap.put("rdf","<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>");
    try{
        model.setNsPrefixes(prifixMap);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*
```

It always throws a java.lang.NullPointerException when it executes the line of model.setNsPrefixes(), and the detail printStackTrace is as following：

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.DatasetPrefixesTDB.readPrefix(DatasetPrefixesTDB.java:86)
>       at org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.GraphPrefixesProjection.get(GraphPrefixesProjection.java:101)
>       at org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.GraphPrefixesProjection.set(GraphPrefixesProjection.java:79)
>       at org.apache.jena.shared.impl.PrefixMappingImpl.setNsPrefix(PrefixMappingImpl.java:75)
>       at org.apache.jena.shared.impl.PrefixMappingImpl.setNsPrefixes(PrefixMappingImpl.java:163)
>       at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.setNsPrefixes(ModelCom.java:1043)
>       at ReadTransaction.(ReadTransaction.java:32)
>       at ReadTransaction.main(ReadTransaction.java:133)

I have checked jena API, and I could not find any solution.

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: With version Apache Jena 3.1.1, I get "org.apache.jena.tdb.TDBException: Allocation attempt on NodeTableReadonly" which is correct.  The code above has "dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ)". It got passed the point in the stacktrace.

Comment: Other possible causes are non-transactional use at sometime in the past (another JVM run) with an unclean shutdown or two processes accessing the same files.

Comment: @AndyS thanks a lot for your comments, it is indeed about the unclean end of a transaction,  I generated the data files again, and the exception did not occur any more.

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me:

```
    Location location = Location.create("target/DBLP");
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(location);
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE); // changed from READ to WRITE
    Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
    HashMap<String, String> prefixMap = new HashMap<>();
    prefixMap.put("rdf", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"); // removed '<' and '>'
    try {
        model.setNsPrefixes(prefixMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The key is to change the transaction type from `READ` to `WRITE`. You are trying to write data so you must be in a write transaction!